# Stopping blank cells in a datagridview - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a DataGridView on one of my forms that the user can edit and then update so changes are made to the database it is linked to. For this reason i do not want any of the cells to be left blank. Currently i am using this code:

```
    If datagrdSnippets.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value Is Nothing Then
        ' Show the user a message
        MsgBox("Please ensure the cell has been given a value")

        ' Fail validation (prevent them from leaving the cell)
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
```

In the cell validating property of the DSG, however when i edit a cell and leave it blank nothing happens. Is there something wrong in my code or do i need to use another method?

Please Note: This is in VB.NET and i am currently using the CellValidating event.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Value` is not the property to be checked in the `CellValidating Event`, but `e.FormattedValue`. The `Value` property you are using in your code does not reflect the current cell value, but the last validated one. Sample code:

```
Private Sub datagrdSnippets_CellValidating(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles datagrdSnippets.CellValidating

     If (e.FormattedValue = "Value I want to avoid") Then e.Cancel = True

End Sub
```

Note that this event is called more than just when the user inputs a value and thus a `MsgBox` "without any restriction" shouldn't be put here (you have to set something (boolean flags, for example) making sure that the user is the one provoking this method to be called).

Comment: @CharlieStuart You are welcome! If you don't have any other doubt, please, mark this as the right answer.